# How to call DBI connect parameters from text file in perl script?

Tags: perl, file

I'm having a code in which i'm extracting data from table and displaying the O/P. But i want to give connection string from txt file(not hardcoded in script) . Can anyone help how i can provide below values from input file.

```
$dbh = DBI->connect( 'dbi:Oracle:DB_INST',"USER","PASS")
    or die "Database connection not made: $DBI::errstr";
```

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$ENV{ORACLE_HOME}='/ora/11.2.0.3';
$LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/ora/11.2.0.3/lib';
use Shell;
use DBI ;
use CGI ;
my $cgi = new CGI;
print $cgi->header;
my $dbh;
$CGI_ST = new CGI;
#################### FUNCTIONS DECLARATION ########################################################
sub Start_HTM
{
        print "<html>\n\n";
        print "<title>LOGICAL DATE CHECK</title>\n\n";
        print "<body>\n<center>\n";
        print "<hr><h1 align=center><font color=#FFA500><u>LOGICAL DATE CHECK</u></font></h1>\n";
}
sub End_HTM
{
        print "<a href=\"#\" onClick=window.close()>Close Window</a></b></small>";
        print "</center>\n</body>\n</html>";
}
sub DisBackButton
{
        print "<br><br><br><INPUT TYPE=button value=Back onClick=history.back()>";
}
####################################################################################################
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
open (FILE,"header.asp");
my $file = <FILE>;
close(FILE);
print "$file";
print "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=JavaScript>";
print "</script>";
my $environment=$CGI_ST->param("environment");
my $product=$CGI_ST->param("product");
Start_HTM();
if ( "$product" eq "2" && "$environment" eq "MPET" ) {
print $cgi->start_html(-title=>'Basic CGI');
# you should change the connect method call to use the DBD you are
# using. The following examples all use DBD::ODBC and hence the
# first argument to the connect method is 'dbi:ODBC:DSN'.
my $dsn = "DBI:Oracle:$db_inst";
$dbh = DBI->connect( 'dbi:Oracle:DB_INST',"USER","PASS") or die "Database connection not made: $DBI::errstr";
my $sql = qq{SELECT logical_date,logical_date_type from logical_date where expiration_date is null };
my $sth = $dbh->prepare( $sql ) || die $dbh->errstr;
$sth->execute() || die $dbh->errstr;
print $cgi->table( { -border=>"1" } );
 while (@data = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
 $Logical_Date_O = $data[0];
 $Logical_Date_B = $data[1];
 $Logical_Date_R = $data[2];
print "<tr><td><font color='black'>$Logical_Date_O</font></td>
<td>$Logical_Date_B</td><td>$Logical_Date_R</td></tr>\n";
}
} 
print $cgi->end_table;
print $cgi->end_html;
```

Comment: Are you asking how to read a line from a text file? Your code already does that! (`open (FILE,"header.asp");
my $file = <FILE>;
close(FILE);`)

Comment: I want to call - ' DB_INST',"USER","PASS" from input file.
And  value will go to below line. 

 $dbh = DBI->connect( 'dbi:Oracle:DB_INST',"USER","PASS")
    or die "Database connection not made: $DBI::errstr";

Answer (score 1):

You want to parse database credentials from properties file instead of hard coding it. Create `ini` file and enter credentials into them and then use [`Config::IniFiles`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::IniFiles) to extract value out of them.

Then, You can pass those values to `DBI` and connect to database.

```
my $cfg = Config::IniFiles -> new( -file => 'path/config/database_config.ini' );

my $dbinst = $cfg -> val( 'DATABASE', 'DBINST' );
my $dbuser = $cfg -> val( 'DATABASE', 'DBUSER' );
my $dbpass = $cfg -> val( 'DATABASE', 'DBPASS' );

my $dbh = DBI->connect( "dbi:Oracle:$dbinst", $dbuser, $dbpass)
    or die "Database connection not made: $DBI::errstr";
```

Here is config file:

```
[DATABASE]
  # DB string
  DBINST=XXX
  # database username
  DBUSER=XXX
  # database password
  DBPASS=XXX
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a file database.conf and you can write it in any format CSV, XLS or simple delimited Flat file so that you can easily parse it. I'm considering a format where I'm using '=' as a separator.

```
# filename database.conf
HOST=dbi:Oracle:DB_INST
USER=USER,
PASSWORD=PASS
```

Now in your perl script use following code for retrieving it:

```
my $db_conf_file = 'database.conf';
my $delimiter = '='; # You can change the delimiter accordingly
my %db;

open(my $FH, '<', $db_conf_file) or die "Could not open $db_conf_file";

while(my $line = <$FH>){
  chomp $line;
  my @fields = split $delimiter , $line;
  $db->{$fields[0]} = $fields[1];
}

close($FH);

$dbh = DBI->connect($db->{HOST}, $db->{USER},$DB->{PASSWORD})
  or die "Database connection not made: $DBI::errstr";
..............
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have code that reads data from a file:

```
open (FILE,"header.asp");
my $file = <FILE>;
close(FILE);
```

So I'm not really sure what problem you are having.

Let's assume that you put the details in a file called credentials.txt which looks like this like this:

```
Oracle:DB_INST:USER:PASS
```

You could then write a subroutine called `get_credentials()` which looks like this:

```
sub get_credentials {
  my $cred_file = 'credentials.txt';
  open my $cred_fh, '<', $cred_file
    or die "Can't open $cred_file: $!\n"

  my $data = <$cred_fh>;
  chomp $data;
  return split /:/, $data;
}
```

You would then call it like this:

```
my ($type, $instance, $user, $pass) = get_credentials();
my $dbh = DBI->connect( "dbi:$type:$instance", $user, $pass)
  or die "Database connection not made: $DBI::errstr";
```

A few other comments on your code.

- **Always** include `use strict` and `use warnings` in your code.
- Why `use Shell`? I don't think you use it?
- You create two CGI objects (`$cgi` and `$CGI_ST`). You only need one.
- We've known since the last millennium that putting raw HTML inside your Perl code is a terrible idea. Look at using templates to separate HTML from Perl.
- You print two CGI headers (`print $cgi->header` and `print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"`. That's one too many.
- Always check the return value from `open()` (`open (FILE,"header.asp") or die ...`)
- Use the three-arg version of `open()` and lexical filehandles (`open (my $fh, '<', 'header.asp') or die ...`).
- Don't quote variables unnecessarily (`print "$file"` is better written `print $file` and `if ( "$product" eq "2" && "$environment" eq "MPET" )` is better written `if ( $product eq "2" && $environment eq "MPET" )`.
- I think you mean `$cgi->start_table()`, not `$cgi->table()`. But the [HTML generation functions have been deprecated](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod#HTML-Generation-functions-should-no-longer-be-used). Please don't use them.

Finally, and most importantly, CGI is old technology. Please read [CGI::Alternatives](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives) and switch to a modern technology that is based on PSGI.